# specific request odoo with many2many relation

Tags: python, orm, odoo

The dysfunctions module has a many2many relation with non-conformity module, when I click on non-conformity page on the notebook, I want to only view the list of non-conformities that have 'dysfunction' as origin.

this is the dysfunction code:

```
    nonconformity_ids= fields.Many2many(
        'nonconformity',
        'dysfunction_nonconformity_rel',
        'dysfunction_id',
        'nonconformity_id',
        'Non conformities'
```

It brings me all non-conformity records on the non-conformity table

Comment: there's no point of showing all records if I only need to see non-conformities that have dysfunction as origin